# How to wrap a container inside a map function with conditional in JSX - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dictionary, jsx

So I have an array of objects that are iterated by a `.map()` function, inside it I want to have a condition, if the object index is `> 1` I want to wrap it in a `div` with a class.

Here's what I've got so far, but it doesn't wrap all videos in one single `.main-videos` `div`:

Thanks

```
object.map((object, index) => {
return (
    <>

        {index === 0 && (
            <div className="main-image" >
            {<img>}
            </div>
        )}

        {index > 1 && (
            <div className="main-videos">
            {<video>}
            </div>
        )}
</>
);
})}


What I basically want to do is this:


object.map((object, index) => {
return (
    <>

        {index === 0 && (
            <div className="main-image" >
            {<img>}
            </div>
        )}

        {index === 1 && (<div className="main-videos">)}
            {index > 1 && (<video>)}
        {index === object.length && (</div>)}
        
</>
);
})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the `<img />` outside of the loop, and slice the loop to render the `<video />` inside the video container:

```
const Example = () => {
  if(!object.length) return null; // don't render anything when there aren't any items

  return (
    <>
      <div className="main-image" >
        <img />
      </div>
      
      <div className="main-videos">
        {object.slice(1).map(() => (
          <video />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
};
```

If the `object` array comes from props or state, you can use destructuring with array rest to get an array of videos:

```
const Example = ({ object: [img, ...videos] }) => {
  if(!img) return null; // don't render anything when there aren't any items

  return (
    <>
      <div className="main-image" >
        <img />
      </div>
      
      <div className="main-videos">
        {videos.map(() => (
          <video />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, after @norbitrial 's comment, slice seems better than a conditional. Awesome

Answer (score 1):

I would try a bit differently as the following:

```
<div className={index === 0 ? 'main-image' : 'main-videos'}>
   { index === 0 ? <img /> : <video /> }
</div>
```

Of course the necessary attributes are missing but you can see the logic. I like to use conditional rendering with [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Read from the documentation:

> The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands: a condition followed by a question mark (?), then an expression to execute if the condition is truthy followed by a colon (:), and finally the expression to execute if the condition is falsy. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if statement.

In this way you don't need also the **React.Fragement** `<></>` because you have a single element.

Comment: Great, @norbitrial but if I place that inside the map function will wrap every video on main-videos, but thanks to your answer I may found the way, maybe rendering the image outside the `map` function and then just render if the index is bigger than 0?